# Create Trigger on a table with clustered columnstore index - Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, columnstore

I am trying to create a trigger on a table which has a columnstore clustered index. Whenever someone updates it logs the record in the audit schema table.
When I execute the `Create Trigger` SQL, getting this error

> CREATE TRIGGER on table 'dbo.report' failed because you cannot create a trigger on a table with a clustered columnstore index. Consider enforcing the logic of the trigger in some other way, or if you must use a trigger, use a heap or B-tree index instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_report 
ON dbo.[Report] 
after UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO [Audit].[Report] 
                      (userid, 
                       department, 
                       modifydate)
           SELECT [UserId] = CURRENT_USER,
           D.* FROM   deleted D 
           WHERE  CURRENT_USER NOT IN (SELECT accountname 
                                      FROM 
                 dbo.[account]) 
      END
```

Comment: What help are you looking for? The error is clear is it not?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a trigger you'll have to make the table a Clustered Index or Heap.  You can then add a non-clustered Columnstore index, but the row data will be stored twice.

Comment: the table doesn't have any unique column where I can create a PK with clustered, in that case what needs to be done?

Comment: Add an identity column?

Comment: Or make the Clustered PK on all the columns, or make it a heap.

Comment: @DaleK, I have to check if this option is feasible.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Every column on the table has duplicate values, do you think it's possible to add PK on those?

Comment: Adding a PK will add an automatic uniqueifier if the data is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

1. Rename your table to <whatever>
2. Create a view that does nothing beside a simple SELECT <all_columns> FROM <whatever> and has the original table name (so you do not have to change your code). Do NOT use SELECT *, this can lead to strange and hard to find problems, when you add / remove / change table columns later.
3. Create an INSTEAD OF trigger on this VIEW (!) which does your audit stuff AND "delegates" the UPDATE / DELETE to the renamed table